# Split mpeg-4 movies by the chapter

Tags: mac, video, quicktime, trim

I have often a tedious job where I need to split movies by the chapter. (The videos have multiple audio tracks & subtitles and have defined chapters)

I can do this in Quicktime, but it's a very manual process !!
Therefore I'm looking for a way / app / .... that takes my video and splits it in multiple videos for each chapter. Simple split, no transcoding or anything. (It would be an added bonus if it was possible to alter the id3 meta data in 1 go as well)
Again, I can do this - sorta - with Quicktime, but I want a more productive way.

Thanks for any feedback !!  let me know if you need more info.
D

Answer (score 1):

## Movie Splitter

You can split your `.mp4` movie without transcoding using [Movie Splitter](https://miln.eu/moviesplitter/) – which I wrote [for my own needs](https://stories.miln.eu/graham/2018-06-29-splitting-more-movie-formats/).

There is a demo you can download and try.

[image: Miln Movie Splitter for macOS]

### Splitting and Trimming Custom Sections

Movies can be automatically split by embedded chapter markers, halved into two, or quartered into four. Version 1.4 added the options to let you select custom ranges to be extracted – by scrubbing or through keyboard input for fine grained control.

[image: custom ranges in Movie Splitter for macOS]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I 'll check it out. (Although I'm certainly not against paying for apps, I do have a dislike against recurring fees)

Comment: The [licence covering Movie Splitter](https://store.miln.eu) does not auto-renew. Pay for as long as the software is worthwhile to you. On a broader scale, sadly, Apple has changed the Mac software market and is changing the expectations of customers.